# Text alignment not working in drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown menu but the text always is dropping down to the right of where the original list item is. I have been messing with different text-align settings but cant seem to get it right. My HTML is available [here](http://www.cooswatershed.org/newhome2). My CSS code is as follows:

```
#navMenu,
#navMenu ul {
list-style: none;
height: 10px;
}
#navMenu {
float: left;
}
#navMenu > li {
float: left;
padding-right: 15px;
}
#navMenu li a {
display: block;
height: 2em;
line-height: .75em;
padding: 0 1.5em;
text-decoration: none;
font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #000000;
text-align: end;

}
#navMenu > li > a {
color: #fff;
align: left;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
}
#navMenu > li:hover > a {
background: #f09d28;
color: #000;
}

#navMenu ul {
position: absolute;
display: none;
align: left;
width: auto;
height: 50px;
background-color: #AAAAAA;
z-index: 999;
}
#navMenu ul li a {`enter code here`
list-style-position:inside;
}
#navMenu li:hover ul {
display: block;

}
```

Comment: Please provide more information, like the HTML. You can use Stack Snippets to great affect here. Also, consider limiting both your HTML and CSS to the least amount needed to demonstrate the problem. See [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips. As it is, this question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subnav `ul` creates a `padding`.
Give the subnav `ul` a `padding: 0`. This should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is adding some left padding to `ul` by default.  You need to remove that padding:

```
#navMenu ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

You may also want to consider using a [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) to prevent problems like these.

Answer (score 1):

You have some additional padding to the left of the `<ul>` in the subnav. Fix it by adding this css:

```
#navMenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}
```

Note: `height: auto;` fixes the height of the subnavs.

Also consider adding a CSS reset such as this one: http://www.cssreset.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul#navMenu ul {
padding-left: 0;
}
```

That will make sure you only hit your nested ul's and not the top-level ul's